# How to using kubectl access the vm cluster on another machine

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

This is the picture.[picture Nginx and cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4C6x.png)

I have to deploy Kubernetes on an old Mac mini just for learning k8s. And I use Multipass to create 3 VM called master, slave01, and slave02. For now, I want to access it using my laptop. so I set up Nginx on the Mac mini and config just like this. `10.77.38.37:6443` is the endpoint of node master.

```
stream{
        upstream api {
                server 10.77.38.37:6443;
        }
        server {
                listen 7777;
                proxy_pass api;
                proxy_timeout 20s;
        }
}
```

I just put the '~/.kube/config' of the master node into my laptop's config. And I change the ip `10.77.38.37:6443` to `192.168.31.84:7777`. `192.168.31.84` is the ip address of Mac mini.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://10.77.38.37:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 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
    client-key-data: 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
```

Finally, I get this.

```bash
$ k get pods
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.77.38.37, not 192.168.31.84
```

Any practical suggestions about this?

Comment: what is `192.168.31.84` ?

Comment: it's the ip address of the macmini, the host machine of VMs. @P....

Comment: Can you try to follow this? https://github.com/joelek/multipass/blob/master/readme.md#multiple-hostnames apparently in the SAN field there is no mention of 192.168.31.84